# How can I have a space character after the word that I use split function in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying another way without using replace() function, and this is my code.

Input:

```
string = 'You are my sunshine, you are my everything.'
repstr = 'are'
repwth = 'were'

for a in string.split():
    if a not in repstr:
        print(a, end = ' ')
    else:
        print(repwth, end = ' ')
```

Output:

`You were my sunshine, you were my everything.`

I try to have a message in the same line of f-strings format, But I wonder how to have a spacebar in the output, and why is it not have any spacebar in my output. I really curious about it.

This is my code.

Input:

```
string = 'You are my sunshine, you are my everything.'
repstr = 'are'
repwth = 'were'

rev = ''

for a in string.split():
    if a not in repstr:
        rev += a
    else:
        rev += repwth

for b in string:
    if b == ' ':
        rev += ' '

print(f'The output string: {rev}')
```

Output:

`The output string: Youweremysunshine,youweremyeverything.`

Thanks.

Comment: `str.split` splits along the whitespace *and removes it*, so when you concatenate the split strings back since you don't add spaces the result doesn't have spaces. This has nothing to do with f-strings. Your second loop just adds a bunch of spaces at the end of the concatenated string, which... why?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `string.replace('are', 'were')` or `re.sub(r'\bare\b', 'were', string)`?

Comment: @Masklinn, Is that mean I have to use another way to create a spcebar?. Sorry for my english is not good.

Comment: Change `rev += a` to the following: `rev += a + " "`

Comment: @InSync, I did it and get the output that I want easily. I want to try another way to not use any replace() function. Sorry for my english is bad.

Comment: @Joe, The output is correct!. Can you explain more why I don't have any spacebar?. I just start learn python around 1 month.

Comment: Where should the space character between the words come from? When you use `split` you get a list of strings without the spaces. In your second example you add spaces, but you add them at the end of your string, so you don't see them when you print the value. Replace `rev += ' '` with `rev += '#'` and you'll see.

Comment: Additionally: You have a mistake in your algorithm. If you define `string = 'This is a problem'` you'll get `Thisiswereproblem   `. You don't want to use `if a not in repstr:` but `if a != repstr:`.

Comment: And just for fun: Your second approach could be written in one line with a generator expression: `print(f'The output string: {" ".join(word if word != repstr else repwth for word in string.split())}')`

Comment: @ArnuC., Matthias has answered the question you asked me.

Comment: @Matthias, Thank you for your explanation. I understand now!. But write in one line with a generator expression is too hard for me HaHaHa. By the way, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gets the desired output

```
string = 'You are my sunshine, you are my everything.'
repstr = 'are'
repwth = 'were'

rev = ''

for a in string.split():
    if a not in repstr:
        rev =rev+ a+ ' '
    else:
        rev=rev+repwth+' '

print(f'The output string: {rev}')
```

output:

```
The output string: You were my sunshine, you were my everything.
```